# How to apply Bayesian Optimization to a function depending only on categorical variables?

Tags: bayesian, categorical-data, optimization, bayesian-optimization

I would like to apply Bayesian Optimization (BO) to a black-box function depending only on multiple categorical variables. In my application, each categorical variable has 3 possible categories. I have 2 questions:

1. BO usually utilizes a *surrogate* function based on Gaussian Processes that approximates the true black-box function to minimize. How this should be adapted to deal with purely categorical variables?
2. BO is known to be less effective for variable space of dimension larger than 20. I understand that this threshold is only a rough estimate, but can I expect BO to still be effective for a function with more than 20 arguments, given the fact that these variables are all categorical (with 3 possible categories)?